# Creating a new item with "/" in Itemname

Tags: powershell-extensions, content-management

I am trying to create a new item in Sitecore from Powershell and using the below command in ISE

*New-Item -Path "master:\content\home" -Name "A/B Demo" -ItemType "Sample/SampleType"*

So my expectation is an item with "A/B Demo" gets created in CMS under home. But getting an error

**New-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'master:\content\home\A\B Demo'**

How should I overcome this error. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: You cannot have `/` in item names. Pass your name through ItemUtil.ProposeValidItemName before storing it. Set your original name as DisplayName instead.

Comment: @MarkCassidy: Ok. How to do it from Powershell? Is there any command equivalent to ItemUtil.ProposeValidItemName?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Display name

first step you have to propose valid item name

```
$name= Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemUtil.ProposeValidItemName("A/B Demo")
```

or you can use the below function to clean the name

```
function SanitizeName{
 $args[0].Replace(".", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("-", "").Replace("&amp;", "").Replace(":", "").Replace("""", "").Replace("#", "")
}
```

to use the name "A/B Demo"

use this command

```
$itemPath="master:/sitecore/content/home"+"/"+$name
$item=New-Item -Path $itemPath -ItemType "Sample/SampleType"
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$item["__Display Name"] = "A/B Demo" 
$item.Editing.EndEdit()
```

Answer (score 0):

As others already said in the comments, you cannot have `/` character in your item name and you should use the `ItemUtil.ProposeValidItemName` method.

If you need to use it in Sitecore Powershell, you can use the following line to validate/format/escape item's name:

```
$itemName = [Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemUtil]::ProposeValidItemName('A/B Tests')
```

You can also include the `/` character as part of the display name instead.